# How to make a prediction to a private Vertex AI endpoint with Node.js client libraries?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Documentation on this is a bit vague at the time of posting https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/using-private-endpoints#sending-prediction-to-private-endpoint , they only mention how to do it with curl.

I would like to use the node.js client library if possible, but I've only managed to find examples that don't use a private endpoint ie: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-ai-platform/blob/main/samples/predict-custom-trained-model.js .

I've read through the type definitions of `PredictionServiceClient` imported from `@google-cloud/aiplatform` and didn't find a way to plug in my private endpoint. I've tried making the request anyway by simply specifying the resource name by doing `const endpoint = projects/${project}/locations/${location}/endpoints/${endpointId}` but this leads to the following error:

```
Error: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 0
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/vitor/vertexai/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:81:24)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/vitor/vertexai/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:343:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/vitor/vertexai/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:462:34)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/vitor/vertexai/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:424:48)
    at /home/vitor/vertexai/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call-stream.ts:323:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  code: 13,
  details: 'Received RST_STREAM with code 0',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
(async () => {
        const client = new v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient();
        const location = "****";
        const project = "****";
        const endpointId = "****"
        const endpoint = `projects/${project}/locations/${location}/endpoints/${endpointId}`;

        const parameters = {
            structValue: {
                fields: {},
            },
        };

        const toInstance = (obj: any) => (
            {
                structValue: {
                    fields: {
                        ****
                    }
                }
            });

        const instance = toInstance(****);
        const instances = [instance];

        const res = await client.predict({
            instances,
            endpoint,
            parameters
        });
        console.log(res);
    })();
```

Is it possible to make this kind of request atm?

Comment: A curl is a simple API call. Why you can't do it?

Comment: I need to set authentication when making a curl request and I 'don't want to manage authentication if I'm running code inside google's infrastructure since they'll handle this for me as long as I use the client libraries.

Comment: Private endpoint doesn't required authentication, but required to be in the same VPC. Your issue is not clear...

Comment: As guillaume is saying, your issue is not clear

Comment: The issue is that I wanted to use the Node.js client library to request predictions to a private endpoint and I can't figure out how to tell the PredictionServiceClient to use my private endpoint. I thought I had to pass credentials with curl but since I don't I might as well just use curl. tks!

Comment: Did you try from a VM in the same VPC as your VertexAI peering?

Comment: Yeah, all tests were done in a VM in the same VPC as VertexAi. HTTP requests to the private endpoint with curl or axios were working fine. I just couldn't find a way to make the requests using the client library.

Comment: Another question, why don't you want to manage authentication into your project?

Comment: Because GCP handles this for me. If a project is running under some service account then that project should have the credentials and permissions of that service account. Instantiating clients with credentials that I have created has given me headaches before. Like for example the credentials not being available in production or being commited to git history. For example, I think 'new Firestore()' is a better way to go about things than 'new Firestore({credentials})'.

Comment: Based on this [doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1532) it looks like the problem is within the library that you are using and isn't related to GCP.

Answer (score 2):

I had to initialize the client using the following in order to get it to behave as documented.

```
const client = new PredictionServiceClient({
apiEndpoint: 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
```

});